# Is it possible to fetch wall posts from my facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am fetching the wall post from my FB page using Javascript API as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init({
               appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               xfbml      : true,
               version    : 'v2.1'
       });

       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //console.log('Logged in.');
        }
         else {
             FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                 console.log(response);
                 FB.api('/153466xxxxxxxx/posts', function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                 });

               } else {
                 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
               }
             }, {scope: ''});
         }
       });
   };

   (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
});
```

however, this needs the user to login and allow permissions to the app. Is it possible for me, using PHP  FB SDK, to fetch the wall post from my account ONLY and show it on my webpage without asking the users to login to their Fb account.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a Facebook Page it´s quite easy, all you need is an **App Access Token**:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

The Facebook SDKs will use an App Token automatically if no user is logged in, but you can also just add the Access Token. Be careful though, don´t use the easy way to create an App token, which is just a combination of App ID and App Secret:

```
var accesstoken = APPID + '|' + APPSECRET;
```

Now if you use that one on the client with JavaScript, your App Secret will be visible to everyone, which is very bad. I would suggest using PHP for this, either with the PHP SDK or simple CURL calls. If you really want to use JavaScript only, just visit the first link i posted and check out how to generate an App Token with a Graph API call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

For a User Profile it´s a lot harder, because you do need a User Token for that. And even an Extended User Token is only valid for 60 days. After that, you need to refresh it manually. But User Profiles should not be used for that anyway.

Comment: But I guess User needs to login once to generate this access token. Right ?

Comment: A User Token: yes. If the user is NOT logged in, the SDK should use an App Token. But i would not count on it, and since you don´t need to login for an App Token you better just use PHP to get the feed.

Comment: for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/ - this is how you can use curl with the graph api.

Comment: CURL Calls seems to be right for me to do. I will try it now and let you know soon.